# jQuery closest problem with classes

Tags: jquery, closest

Here is my jQuery

```
$('.vote_down').live('click', function() {
    var $votes = $(this);
    var c_id = $(this).closest('.c_id').val();
    var c_vote = $(this).closest('.c_vote').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "votes.php",
        data: "c_id="+c_id+"&c_vote="+c_vote,
        success: function(html){
            $votes.parent().html(html);             
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the html it's pulling from:

The vars `c_id` and `c_vote` currently get nothing

```
<div class="votes">
    <input type="hidden" class="c_id" value="5" />
    <input type="hidden" class="c_vote" value="2" />
    <img src="down_vote.png" border="0" class="vote_down" alt="Down Vote" />
</div>
```

Comment: SHouldn't you be using closest() on the parent of $votes?

Comment: @Maurycy Zarzycki: No, then it would look for ancestors of the parent.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Ah, ok. I remember reading about closest() the other day and I could've sworn that I saw something about descendants but I guess it must've been my imagination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong function. `closest` gets the closest **ancestor**. The input fields are not ancestors of the image, they are **siblings**.

You can do:

```
var c_id = $(this).prevAll('.c_id').val();
var c_vote = $(this).prevAll('.c_vote').val();
```

or if the order is always the same:

```
var c_id = $(this).prev().prev().val();
var c_vote = $(this).prev().val();
```

**Reference**: [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/), [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

Comment: +1 Yay! You could also use `siblings()` in case that HTML flips itself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.vote_down').live('click', function() {
    var $votes = $(this);
    var c_id = $(this).prev('input.c_id:first').val();
    var c_vote = $(this).prev('input.c_vote:first').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "votes.php",
        data: "c_id="+c_id+"&c_vote="+c_vote,
        success: function(html){
            $votes.parent().html(html);             
        }
    });
});
```

-edited after your comment, true my bet, I ment prev()-
If you always use this HTML structure, why not use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/); ? Try the above code

Comment: `previousSibling` is not a jQuery function.

Comment: Especially not with two `b`s. Also, it is a property in the native DOM API, not a method. I think you want `prev()`.

Comment: @alex, you beat me to it by 12 seconds ;-)

Comment: `prev()` wouldn't work for `input.c_id`. `prev` only gets the previous sibling *if* it matches the selector, not the previous one which matches the selector.